# How do I continuously compare a value to a values in a csv (Python)?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, variables, compare

For a project I need to ensure that the discharge of a reservoir never dips below demand over a year, however demand varies over the year. I need to be able to compare the value of discharge at a time step to the value of demand at that same time step, any ideas?

Here's the snippet of code if that helps:

```
dam = dict()

dam['Smax'] = 22000000000
dam['hmax'] = 107
dam['Amax'] = 765000000
#dam['A'] = 'Needed relation between S and A'
#dam['h'] = 'Needed relation between S and h'
dam['Pm'] = pd.read_csv('input\Precipitation Dam Site.csv',
                                       sep=',',
                                       header=None).values.flatten()
dam['Em'] = pd.read_csv('input\Evaporation Dam Site.csv',
                                       sep=',',
                                       header=None).values.flatten()
dam['Demand'] = pd.read_csv('input\Downstream Demands.csv',
                                       sep=',',
                                       header=None).values.flatten()
dam['Inflow'] = Q_res_in.copy() 

Demand=pd.DataFrame(data=dam['Demand'])


#Net Precipitation
#E_res = dam['Em']*dam['A']
#P_res = dam['Pm']*dam['A']
#P_Net = P_res - E_res

#Initial Storage/(Change for Operational Years)
S_init = 0
S=S_init

#Base Outflow Requirements
Q_out = dam['Inflow']*0.2

#Storage over time
for n in parameters['t'][:-1]:

    # get day number if more than 1 year is considered
    d = np.mod(n, 365)

    # create a pandas datetime object based on year and day of year
    dtime = pd.to_datetime(f'2013-{parameters["t"][d]+1}', format='%Y-%j')

    # get month based on datetime
    m = dtime.month

    # get days in month based on datetime
    dpm = dtime.daysinmonth

    # get day based on datetime
    day = dtime.day
    
    #S_change=((P_Net)+(dam['Inflow']-Q_out))*86400
    
    if n in range (0,150): #temp range
        if S > dam['Smax']*0.9:
            Q_out=dam['Inflow']*1.5
        else:
            Q_out=Q_out 

    elif n in range(150,175):
        if S > dam['Smax']*0.1: #temp
            Q_out=Q_out+100 #temp
        else:
            Q_out=Q_out
        
    elif n in range(175,365):
        if S > dam['Smax']*0.9:
            Q_out=dam['Inflow']*1.5
        else:
            Q_out=Q_out  
    
   #if Q_out <= Demand:
        #Q_out=Demand*1.1
    #else:
        #Q_out=Q_out
    
    S=S+S_change
```

I first attempted to compare them in a loop, expecting the data to be read out one by one, it spat out "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()." After that I tried to first convert the file into a dataframe to use but had no luck with that as well ending with "raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: (0, 0)"